# How to make network adapter work only for specific application on windows 10?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ethernet

I'm using my Wi-Fi home to browsing internet and whatching youtube, on other side i connect my 3g phone with my computer using usb threading settings to play fortnite, what i want to do is to make this network adapter which receive internet from my 3g phone only wrk for my fortnite game, and the Wi-Fi adapter for all other my desktop application. and make all other application prevent to connect with the adapter which receive internet from 3g phone.

Edited: i found on the internet software called force bind ip, that software make inject self to the applications to do the job, but my questoin now is it safe to use with fortnite game?!

Thanks in advance

Comment: We can't say whether it's safe to use for your game. Does it work? Then it's good.

Comment: I send message to epic support to see if it safe or no. I'll be back with the feedback

Comment: The said to me if this will not make change to game files, then it will be safe. So i think this is safe.